# MapAT and GeoPosition

Tags: list-manipulation, geographics

I just experienced a problem applying `GeopPosition` via `MapAt`. Here a MWE. Given a list of data:

```
    list = {{"Japan", 36, 138, "more data"}, {"Singapore", 1.28, 103.8, 
   "more data"}}
```

I want to convert the second and third entry to a `GeoPosition` with:

```
MapAt[GeoPosition, list, {All, 2 ;; 3}]
```

this is not working, output:

```
{{"Japan", GeoPosition[36], GeoPosition[138], 
  "more data"}, {"Singapore", GeoPosition[1.28], GeoPosition[103.8], 
  "more data"}}
```

but this works:

```
GeoPosition /@ list[[All, 2 ;; 3]]
```

output:

```
{GeoPosition[{36, 138}], GeoPosition[{1.28, 103.8}]}
```

Can someone tell me why this is so as it is?

Comment: It's not a problem with `GeoPosition[]`: `MapAt[f, Array[C, {2, 4}], {All, 2 ;; 3}]` Try this instead: `{#1, GeoPosition[{#2, #3}], #4} & @@@ list`.

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties Thanks for this comment, My "problem" was the the "output" of `list[All,2;;3]`is the list (!) `{list[[2]],list[[3]] }`and this is NOT fed to `GeoPosition` the single values are fed in.